# Excel formula to select data range based on a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to get the value from column A based on conditions below:
a) column number will be where the value match for (1101,1138,1554...) e.g: 1101 is column B
b) Row number will be where the number 1,2,3.. match in the column that came from condition (a) e.g-B:B  [image]

Comment: So your inputs are like 1554, and 23 and you want to return what ever is in that row in column A?

Comment: Yes based on the inputs in the 2nd row ie 1554 for example and any number available under that column.

Comment: Where are you entering the criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of INDEX-MATCH functions to find the value in column A:A with 2 parameters.

[image: Result]
[image: Example]

Breakdown of Formula:

```
=INDEX(A3:A7,
      MATCH(L2,
         INDEX(B3:G7,0,MATCH(K2,B2:G2,0)),0
      )
 )
```

- The 1st line in the formula is your return range.
- The 2nd line is the row to match the lookup on.
- The 3rd line finds the column for the row lookup by using another INDEX-MATCH.

You'll have to modify the formula to suit your needs of course.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I tried using this but was not aware with the 0 condition that you have used as row number. thanks again!

Comment: @SauravArya no problem! if everything worked fine, don't forget to make this question as answered.